# Filter divs based on class with checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filter divs based on certain classes by using a checkbox form.

I've been using the following fiddle which almost suits my needs:
http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/738/

However if I wrap an extra `<div class="anything">` on top of the Black/Color classes, the filtering no longer works.

```
<div class="Test">
<div class="Black Color">Black, Color</div>
<div class="Black">Black</div>
```

How can I code this to allow for the div's to be wrapped in more divs?

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by: when I wrap an extra on top. You mean a div with another class?

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean an extra div. http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/769/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are hiding all `div` elements in the change handler

```js
$("#filters :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(".colors > div").hide();
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(".colors ." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anything">
    <ul id="filters">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Black"/>
            <label for="filter-categorya">Black</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Color"/>
            <label for="filter-categoryb">Color</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="colors">
    <div class="Black Color">Black, Color</div>
    <div class="Black">Black</div>
    <div class="Black">Black</div>
    <div class="Color">Color</div>
    <div class="Color">Color</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was working with OP on IRC with this one.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="grn_div" name="cb" id="grn_cb" />
<label for="grn_cb">Green</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="red_div" name="cb" id="red_cb" />
<label for="red_cb">Red</label>

<div id="grn_div" > 
    <h2>Greeen SHOW!</h2>
</div>
<div id="red_div">
    <h2> REED WATERMELON</h2>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id*="_div"]').hide();
});

$(':checkbox[name="cb"]').click(function () {
   $("#"+ $(this).val()).toggle();
});
```

This is my solution so it shouldn't conflict much with current setup.